# Understanding the elliptic curve equation by example

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm trying to follow [this](http://ae.hc.cust.edu.tw/new_website/attachments/article/244/Lecture%2015_elliptic%20curves%20II.pdf) tutorial and wonder how the author get the list of points in the elliptic curve. For example, why when you input x=1 you'll get y=7 in point (1,7) and (1,16)?

on intuitive level, I'll do:

```
x=1, 1^3+1+1 mod 23
```

`= 3mod23 = 3` so why we get (1,7) & (1,16).

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious: because $y^2=3\bmod23$ has two solutions: $y=7$ and $y=16$, as verified by $7^2\equiv49\equiv3\pmod{23}$ (the other follows by taking the opposite, $-7\bmod23=23-7=16$)?. If you want a method to solve that other than by trial and error, in the general case there's [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm); or since here we have $23\equiv3\pmod4$ you can use $y=\pm3^{(23+1)/4}\bmod23$

Comment: ohhhh, got it. I totally ignored the y^2. so 7^2≡3mod23 & 16^2≡3mod23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As fgrieu already mentioned, you forgot that the $y$ term in the elliptic curve equation is squared, so for $x= 1$ you have $y^2 = 1^3 + 1 + 1 = 3 \text{ mod } 23$. In order to solve the congruence $y^2 = n \text{ mod } p$ (where $p$ is a prime) you can use the following algorithm ([Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm)):

1. Factor the powers of $2$ out of $p-1$, so in your case write $p-1 = 22 = Q2^S = 11 * 2^1$
2. Pick a value $z$ that is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$ i.e. there exists no $x$ such that $z = x^2 \text{ mod } p$. I picked $7$ at random and verified it's not a quadratic residue via Euler's criterion ($7^{\frac{23-1}{2}} = 22 = -1 \text{ mod } 23$)
3. Set the following values (all calculations done modulo $p$): $$M \gets S(=1)$$ $$c \gets z^Q(7^{11}=22)$$ $$t \gets n^Q(3^{11}=1)$$ $$R \gets n^{\frac{Q+1}{2}}(3^{\frac{11+1}{2}}=16)$$
4. This step involves looping until $t = 1$, which in our case is already true going into this step, so we have $y = R = 16$ as one of our solutions. The other solution can be found by computing $p - R = 23 - 16 = 7$.

Hence we have the two solutions $y = 16, y = 7$ when $x = 1$, yielding the points $(1, 16), (1, 7)$ as expected.